# How to handle user data (via browser) that was entered into the webapp

Tags: python, django, request, ldap

There is a computer running the project. Let the account of this pc be the Owner. I have a user authorization function with LDAP, this function returns me a dictionary in which user data is stored in Active Directory. Querying data from AD using reuest.META['USERNAME']. And it's all working in Owner pc.
If I connect to my webapp from another pc, let his account be Client, request.META gives the Owner data and not the Client. As I noticed, from the Client pc I receive only reuest.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] - it's ip of Client, but i need his name. It turns out that from the Client computer I enter under the Owner's name, which is incorrect.

Please tell me what data the user is sending to the server using a Get request, connecting to the page

Comment: Edgecase, thx for edit!

Comment: No problem at all! :)

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific for us to be able to help you. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: update information

Comment: still looking for an answer. 
Please tell me what data the user is sending to the server using a Get request, connecting to the page